# wrap words in all same selectors with using Dom Objec

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

I get a code from webhelp.pl forum: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dyk9ena/1/)**, which wraps any word in first selector:

```
document.querySelector('p')
```

but when I'd like to add the same for rest 'p' selectors by:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p')
```

then code no work. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single element, which may contain child nodes.

[**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of elements – each of which may contain child nodes. But the list itself does not have a **childNodes** property.

You need to iterate through the **querySelectorAll()** list to operate on each of its element's child nodes in turn:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.abcd')).forEach(function(p) {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(p.childNodes).forEach(function (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      var text = node.nodeValue;

      var words = text.match(/(\S+|\s+)/g);

      words.forEach(function (word) {
        var isWhiteSpace = /^\s+/.test(word);

        if (isWhiteSpace) {
          node.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(word), node);
        } else {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent = word;
          node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
        }
      });

      node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8vufahvd/1)

Comment: Ok, I understood my mistake but you fiddle not wrap child element.. In your example i dont see any `Array.prototype.slice.call`. I dont need it to right work?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function`. The NodeList returned by `.querySelectorAll` doesn't have `.forEach` method.

Comment: Thanks, @Vohuman, it has a `forEach` method in Chrome but possibly not other browsers.  I'll update.

Comment: I've the same message so foreach using wit NodeList isn't  good way?

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using Chromium which works like Chrome and the `NodeList` object doesn't have such method.

Comment: Absolutely sure, it's working fine in 51.0.2704.103 m.

Comment: @ZicoPL, you can add `forEach` as a method to NodeList by doing this:  `NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;`.  However, that may not be the best approach.  I'll keep working on this answer, unless Vohuman wants to take over (which would be fine).

Comment: @ZicoPL, are you hoping to wrap the word "taki" as well as the other words?

Comment: I no need to wrap nested object/string. "taki" with his <b></b> tag can be ignored. Wrap each nested object is too difficult to understand for me..

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion.  It's probably best to use `Array.prototype.slice.call` to iterate a NodeList.  Both `querySelectorAll()` *and* `childNodes` return NodeLists, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok, sure. Right now you made excellent job. I'm so gratefull. Thank you! I haven't thought to use twice `Array.prototype.slice.call`